# how to add field in form in yii1 with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am using date picker widget in my YII1 form. I also have a button to add more dates. When the page is first time loaded the date picker widget works. When I click on add more button, I added the new filed to the from but at that time date picker does not work.

How can I add datepicker widget fields on ajax to a form?

or there is any other way doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is because of  'Id'

`You just change the datepicker displaying attribute from 'Id' to 'Class'`,

Ie,the newely added fields id and already added fields id,s are same so date picker wont work with multiple with same id,so you should change the datepicker displaying attribute from 'ID' to 'Class'

then, it will work fine

Comment: Achu I am using http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/date-time-picker/ this date picker ,IN jquerydatetime.php fileI have change $js = "$('.yiiDateTimePickerClass').datetimepicker($options);";
         $cs->registerScript(__CLASS__ . '.' . "yiiDateTimePickerClass", $js);,
But it is not showing date , but it is showing time .

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax Success re-initialize datepicker

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

your problem will solve.better if you post your code here